# Word for working with people and getting a certain percentage back when you launch a product?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for working with or for someone else (instead of financially backing them) and getting a certain percentage back (profit sharing/ownership) when you launch a product? Kind of like 401k vesting but there is a certain word for it.

Example:

> Would you like to to get paid in a ____ arrangement?

Note: Not financial equity!

Comment: I think your question would benefit from a more specific example. Profit sharing, commission, delayed wages, and equity (even though you say that's not what you're looking for) all seem to apply from your description.

Comment: I found the answer. It is Sweat Equity.

Comment: @SteveMoser - You can answer your own question.  It helps those who come along later with the same or a similar question, especially if you provide [references](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/sweatequity.asp) and an explanation of why it was the correct answer for you.

Comment: @RogerSinasohn Thanks. I think the question was put on hold so I couldn’t answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Sweat Equity**

Instead of put money into a company and getting financial equity you can put work into a company and get sweat equity.